# Is it possible to call the sqlite3_limit() function from SQL

Tags: variables, sqlite, numbers, limit

From Python, I want to reduce the value of SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER from its compiled-in value to a much lower value, for testing purposes.

In practice, I sometimes need to specify many more variables than the compiled-in value allows. Therefore, I chunk the requests. It would be convenient if I could reduce the compiled-in value to something very low, so that I can make sure my chunking method is working when testing with small data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite allows changing limits only by calling `sqlite3_limit()`; there is not `PRAGMA` for this.

However, check out the [Another Python SQLite Wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/apsw/), which has a `Connection.limit()` function.

Comment: Thanks. That is useful for the future. My incremental-addition code works, so the ability to do this is a nice-to-have for me. So for now, I will stick with the sqlite3 API and forego this feature.